# how can I handle errors in laravel mail

Tags: php, laravel-5, error-handling, mailchimp, mandrill

Laravel app sending mails with mandrillapp and Mailchimp. it's working.

How do you handling errors?
How can I know is the mail sent or not?

Mail is send with Mail::sent() in try/catch block.

count(Mail::failures) is always 0. I can't find what type or error is needed to show in failures[]?

I can catch

```
Swift_RfcComplianceException
```

and

```
Swift_TransportException
```

I read the mailchimp documentation but can't find some return of API which says about mail status.

Any idea or suggestion about error handling?

Comment: In the log file, you must find all errors triggers from your app. You can find it int `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: I know where to find log file, but i don't know what exception i must catch to put in log file

Comment: @tome1992 how is your APP_DEBUG in .env file ? Or, maybe php error is hidden.

Comment: APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug

Comment: If you don't know which exception you're getting, best thing you can do is: 1) Catch a standard exception, 2) dd() that exception, usually `$e->getMessage()`, 3) you'll see which exception you're getting. 4) keep try/catching for that exception, but also catch a normal exception, just in case